# php parse xml into array, ignore data between text tags

Tags: php

Backend batch programmer learning something new.  While parsing an xml file I found that when it gets to a  tag, it breaks out all the children but I don't want it to.  I would like to keep everything between the open and close tag as a string.  Been reading a lot and would like some guidance on how to approach this.  My initial thought is to use a different parser.

using the code below to parse the xml:

```
function xml_to_array($xml) {
    $parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $elements);
    xml_parser_free($parser);
    return $elements;
}
```

mockup of the xml.
character text here that descibes something underlined text more text after the underlined https://www.link_tosomewhere.com\')">last remaining part of the text.

array:
[100] => Array
        (
            [tag] => text
            [type] => open
            [level] => 4
            [value] => character text here that descibes something
        )

```
[101] => Array
    (
        [tag] => u
        [type] => complete
        [level] => 5
        [value] => underlined text
    )

[102] => Array
    (
        [tag] => text
        [value] =>  more text after the underlined text
        [type] => cdata
        [level] => 4
    )

[103] => Array
    (
        [tag] => a
        [type] => complete
        [level] => 5
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [href] => javascript:windowPopup('https://www.link_tosomewhere.com')
            )

        [value] => last remaining part of the text.
    )

[104] => Array
    (
        [tag] => text
        [type] => close
        [level] => 4
    )
```

Desired:
[100] => Array
        (
            [tag] => text
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 4
            [value] => character text here that descibes something underlined text more text after the underlined texthttps://www.link_tosomewhere.com\')">last remaining part of the text.
        )

Comment: Can you share your `XML` string?

Comment: <text>Which of the following best describes your <u>household</u> income?<a href="javascript:windowPopup(\'https://www1.pollg.com/demos2009/why_en_US.html\',\'Desired\',\'width=370,height=270,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,title=no\')">
Why do we ask this question?</a></text>